# Improve latency of findUsers query made by node js activedirectory module

Tags: node.js, performance, networking, active-directory

I am expriencing high latency when fetching users from active directory in nodejs.

I am using the node library from npm 'activedirectry'. https://www.npmjs.com/package/activedirectory

The amount of users is relatively not big, About 1000 users...

The time of the query takes between 2 to 4 seconds.

The default query provided by the function findUsers of the 'activedirectory' library is *(&(|(objectClass=user)(objectClass=person))(!(objectClass=computer))(!(objectClass=group)))*.

I added an additional filter on the sAMAccountName field. sAMAccountName=*somePartOfName*

In any case, with or without my addition the query time is still slow.

I don't have full configuration of the active directory server,
But it seems like other platforms on the same network work faster with the active directory but they work with other frameworks, in java and .NET.

What could be the reason for this high latency?

Thanks

```
// ad is configured only with user, password, base dn and url

function findUsers(partOfsAMAccountName) {
    const additionalQuery = `sAMAccountName=*${partOfsAMAccountName}*`;

    return new Promise(resolve => {
        ad.findUsers(additionalQuery, false, (error, users) => {
            if(error) {
                console.error('%j', error);
            }

            resolve(users || []);
        })
    }
}
```

What I am tring to do is to create an autocomplete mechanism based on the usernames of the active directory.

On the same network we have bitbucket server connected to the same active directory server. It seems like from the bitbucket client the autocomplete is much faster. about 1 sec from the client side.

I had already searched for the open souce of bitbucket but didn't find any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea about `node.js`, and have never programmed in the same. But, from the question I feel that default query provided for findUsers() might be the culprit.

> As per Microsoft Docs, LDAP filter for
>   [`(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ad/querying-for-users)
>   is sufficient for determining the users.

In the official documentation for function [`findUsers(opts, callback)`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/activedirectory#findUsers), I can see the argument opts description about *Optional parameters to extend or **override** functionality*.

So, I think you can override the LDAP filter query using the `opts` argument in findUsers function to keep the above advised LDAP filter, and additionally put your sAMAccountName condition in the search query. Please explore on how to override the opts argument, as I can't help you with that.

I am hopeful that the result would be comparatively faster after doing the search this way.

Comment: Thank you, that is much faster.

Comment: @OfekBenYaish - Great, good to know that! Would you please comment on how fast it is, in case it might help future visitors?